# Check valid input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am trying to get valid input from a user by using a while loop. So if the input is not valid I want an error message to come up and repeat itself every time the user does not give valid input

Here is my code -

```rb
def suburb
#user prompt to get information for URL
  puts ' Hey there welcome to house_search! Please which suburb you would like to search...'
  puts '1. sub1 2. sub2'
    suburb_input = input
    while suburb_input != "1" or "2"
        p "please try again"
        suburb_input
    end
end
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to place `gets` in the while statement so that it keeps getting user input until you break from the loop.

```
def suburb
  puts 'Hey there welcome to house_search! Please choose which suburb you would like to search...'
  puts '1. sub1 2. sub2'
  while input = gets.chomp
    if input == '1' || input == '2'
      puts "Jolly good!"
      break # exits the loop
    else 
      puts "please try again" # the loop continues
    end 
  end
end
```

Be wary of using the `or` and `and` operators. They have a lower precedence than `||` and `&&`.

Comment: Though it works, since `gets.chomp` is always truthy the `while` condition is a bit misleading. Perhaps `loop do; input = gets.chomp;...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I do agree that `while true` is somewhat confusing but it is an established idiom. There are actually tons of ways of doing this like `until ["1", "2"].include?(input = gets.chomp); `